# Extracting certain text from a string

Tags: c#

This is the string `/football/players/someplayer`, which is in a `RichTextBox`. What I'm trying to do is copy the text
`someplayer` without knowing the text length.

Here is one example of text I need to parse:

```
href="/football/players/petr-cech" data-ylk="lt:s;sec:mod-stat;slk:plyr;itc:0;tar:uk.sports.yahoo.com;">P. Cech</a></th>
```

I need to extract `petr-cech` from the above string.

Comment: You can also use this:

`string player = yourstring.Substring(yourstring.LastIndexOf("/") + 1);`

Answer (score 0):

You can also use regular expressions

```
var text = @"/football/players/someplayer";
var pattern = @"^.*/(?<player>.*)$";
var regex = new Regex(pattern);
var player = regex.Match(text).Groups["player"];
```